# Lenovo S6000 - Auto power on after connecting charger

Tags: shell, kernel, power-on

I searched the web to automatically power on my lenovo tablet after connecting the charger, but all the guides are for samsung and some other brands. File `/system/bin/playlpm` doesn't exist in lenovo S6000:

```
shell@android:/system/bin $ ls
6620_launcher         bootanimation         dexopt                geomagneticd          ip6tables             mediaserver           netcfg                reboot                sendevent             tc
6620_wmt_concurrency  btconfig              df                    getevent              iptables              memorydumper          netd                  renice                sensorservice         thermal
abcc                  btlogmask             dhcp6c                getprop               keystore              memsicd               netdiag               requestsync           service               thermal_manager
adb                   bu                    dhcp6ctl              grep                  kill                  mfv_ut                netstat               resize2fs             servicemanager        toolbox
aee                   bugmailer.sh          dhcp6s                gsm0710muxd           lenovoSN2             mkdir                 newfs_msdos           rild                  setcc                 top
aee_aed               bugreport             dhcpcd                gsm0710muxdmd2        linker                mke2fs                notify                rildmd2               setconsole            touch
aee_core_forwarder    busybox               dm_agent_binder       gzip                  ln                    mksh                  nvram_agent_binder    rm                    setprop               uiautomator
aee_dumpstate         cat                   dmesg                 hald                  log                   mobile_log_d          nvram_daemon          rmdir                 settings              umount
afm_server            ccci_fsd              dnsmasq               hd                    logcat                modify_ebr.sh         orientationd          rmmod                 sh                    uptime
akmd8963              ccci_mdinit           dpfd                  hdc                   logwrapper            monkey                permission_check      route                 shutdown              vdc
akmd8975              chmod                 drmserver             id                    ls                    mount                 ping                  rtt                   sleep                 vmstat
am                    chown                 du                    ifconfig              lsmod                 msensord              pm                    run-as                smd                   vold
ami304d               cmp                   dualmdlogger          iftop                 lsof                  mtkGD                 poad                  sbchk                 start                 watchprops
app_process           content               dumpstate             ime                   magd                  mtk_agpsd             pppd                  schedtest             stop                  wipe
applypatch            cp                    dumpsys               input                 make_ext4fs           mtkbt                 pppd_dt               schedtop              stp_dump3             wlan_loader
atrace                dalvikvm              em_svr                insmod                matv                  mtpd                  pq                    screencap             superumount           wpa_supplicant
badblocks             date                  ext4_resize           installd              md5                   muxreport             printenv              screenshot            surfaceflinger        xlog
bmgr                  dbus-daemon           factory               ioctl                 md_minilog_util       mv                    ps                    sdcard                svc
bmm050d               dd                    fsck_msdos            ionice                mdlogger              nandread              racoon                sdiotool              sync
boot_logo_updater     debuggerd             fsck_msdos_mtk        ip                    mdnsd                 ndc                   radvd                 send_bug              system_server
```

Is there any universal method for all androids? I may need this for a brandless chinese tablet(but now for lenovo). I just want to power on the android as soon  as charger is connected.

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be following: you need to edit boot.img ramdrive content and have su installed it to work.

unpack boot.img and extract init.rc from ramdrive.
Add following to the end of file:

```
#Check if chargermode and start rebootit service.
on property:ro.bootmode=charger
    start rebootit
```

and after it added following:

```
#rebootit service which command reboot
service rebootit /su/bin/su /system/bin/reboot -c reboot now
    user root
    oneshot
```

then re-pack ramdrive and boot.img and flash it.

Got working with this method on Lenovo TAB 2 A10-30